# How to implement a module into a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I want to implement a module into a class structure.

I do it with simple logic (maybe, you come out with your ideas for the best perfomance):

```
module Tsito
  class Hello
    def say_hello(name)
      puts "Module > Class: Hello #{name}"
    end
  end
end
tsio = Tsito::Hello.new
tsio.say_hello("Sara")
```

But, I could it. What are your ideas?

```
class Hello
  module Tsito
    def say_hello(name)
      puts "Class > Module: Hello #{name}"
    end
  end
end
tsio = Hello.new
#tsio.say_hello("Sara") // Gives an error
```

Comment: Can you say what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a module has nothing to do with the performance. Its main use is code organization (namespacing) and mixins.

Putting classes under a module is what I used to do, but I haven't tried it vice versa. But it's fully valid.

On your second example, you just put a module inside the class, and expected Ruby to include the module to its parent. But it can't be done. You have to do it manually. Just add include at the end of the line:

```
class Hello
  module Tsito
    def say_hello(name)
      puts "Class > Module: Hello #{name}"
   end
  end
  include Tsito 
end
```

Now try

```
Hello.new.say_hello "hola"
```

This will work as you expected.

Remember you need to use `include` wherever you wanted to use the module.

Comment: First of all, i try to implement module library. Then, include from base code. It is ok. But, i was curious how can i do without writing another module libs, etc.. Thanks alot.